# making an arrow with before + after

Tags: html, css

Good day
I have a a link which must have text + arrow looking like this:

[image]

I have done arrow,but dont know how to make that white background 
the thing is i have to use pseudoelements

```css
.hiretext{
 margin-top:185px;
 padding:5px 2px 5px 5px;
 position:absolute;
 background-color: #1a1e27;
 color:white;
 font-family:FrutigerCELight,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
 font-size:20px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 900;
}
.hirelink{
 display:inline-block;  
   width: 0;   
   height: 0; 
 border-top: solid transparent;
 border-bottom: solid transparent;
 border-left: solid black; 
 border-width:7px;
 content:' ';
 }
```

```html
<div class="hiretext">
  <a href="#" class="hirelink">
   hire us
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: just wondering, instead of using such hacks, why don't you just use arrow image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you create from pseudo element. Just change the color.

```css
.hiretext {
  margin-top:105px;
  padding:5px 2px 5px 5px;
  position:absolute;
  color:white;
  font-family:FrutigerCELight,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size:20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.hirelink {
  position: relative;
}

.hirelink:after {
  content: '';
  border-left: 10px solid black;
  border-top: 6px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: -42px;
}

.hirelink:before {
  content: '';
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hiretext">
  <a href="#" class="hirelink"> hire us</a>
</div>
```

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```css
.hiretext {
  padding: 5px 2px 5px 5px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #1a1e27;
  font-family: FrutigerCELight, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 900;
  width: 200px;
}
.hirelink {
  position: relative display: inline-block;
  color: white;
}
.hirelink:after {
  content: "►";
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  margin: auto;
  background: white;
  color: #1a1e27;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 28px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hiretext">
  <a href="#" class="hirelink">
   hire us
  </a>
</div>
```